# Batch script to delete files with specific length names

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I have tried `del "C:\path\?????.txt"` to delete files having name of length 5 characters(abcde.txt etc.).
It does delete the files with 5 char names but it also delete files having less than 5 char name (abc.txt,abcd.txt etc.)
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following complete [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), which uses `where.exe`, will only match, and subsequently try to delete, files whose name contains exactly five characters and the `.txt` extension. *(all you need to do is to use a `?` to represent each character)*.

```batch-file
@SetLocal
@Set "PATHEXT="
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%where.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\New":"?????.txt" 2> NUL"') Do @Del /A/F "%%G"
@EndLocal
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, this is one of them:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "%userprofile%\Desktop\New\*.txt"') do (
    set "str=%%~i"
    if "!str:~5!" == "%%~xi" del "%%~i" /Q /S
)
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, this code works fine but also deletes the files in sub-directories.